# How can I change this Django Application

Tags: python, django, apache

I was tasked with making some changes to a Django application. I've never worked with Django and I am having trouble figuring out how to get my changes to compile and be available online.

What I know so far is that the application is currently available online. netstat tells me that httpd is listening on port 80. My change was made in the myapp/views.py file.

I tried to restart httpd using `services httpd restart` but my changes did not take effect. I've been looking into the issue a bit an I believe that I need to run a command along the lines of:

I tried calling `python manage.py runserver MY.IP.AD.DR:8000` and I get:

python manage.py runserver 129.64.101.14:8000
Validating models...

`0 errors found
Django version 1.4.1, using settings 'cutsheets.settings'
Development server is running at http://MY.IP.AD.DR:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.`

Nice that no errors are found but when I navigate to http://MY.IP.AD.DR:8000/ I just get a "Unable to connect" message from my browser. I tried with port 81 too and had the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried locally running the development server first to make sure that the django project is running as expected? If it is, then it doesn't really sound like a django problem and more like a webserver configuration problem.

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried and I ran into a problem which I detailed in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how your application is set up, I can't really say exactly how to solve this problem.

I can tell you that it's quite common to use two web servers with Django - one handles the static content, and reverse proxies everything else to a different port where the Django app is listening. Restarting the normal HTTP daemon therefore wouldn't affect the Django app, so you need to restart the one handling the Django app. Until you restart it, the prior version of the code will be running.

I generally use Nginx as my static server and Gunicorn with the Django app, with Supervisor used to run Gunicorn, and this is a common setup. I recommend you take a look at the config for the main web server to see if it forwards anything to another port. If so, you need to see what server is running on that port and restart it.

Also, is there a Fabric configuration (fabfile.py)? A lot of people use Fabric to automate Django deployments, and if there is one then there may be a command already defined for deploying.

Comment: Thanks Matt. There is no fabfile.py. I will try to find out if the app is listening on another port.

Comment: I used `netstat -anpt` to list the processes listening to ports. Do you have any suggestions for how to figure out where forwarding might be happening?

Comment: @Mike It tends to be quite a high port. 8080 and 8000 are common choices. Unfortunately most of these servers don't seem to have a default port - it's normally user-defined. You might want to look up some of the common servers used with Django, such as Gunicorn and uwsgi, and then see if any of them are installed. If so, they're probably what you need to look for. However, since the main server will need to forward to the appropriate port anyway, I think your best bet is to look in the config there to find what port it forwards to.

Comment: Again, thanks. What config file should I look at? I checked in /usr/lib/httpd for a config file but I couldn't find one.

Comment: I went into settings.py of my application and found a line `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cutsheets.wsgi.application'`. Could WSGI be what I am looking for?

Comment: @Mike No, WSGI is the name of the specification for the interface between the server and the application. Gunicorn is an example of a web server that supports WSGI.

Comment: @Mike My experience is mainly with Debian and Ubuntu, so take this with a pinch of salt if your OS is something else, but assuming your main server is Apache, then the config file would normally be under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. The naming scheme for Nginx is similar - IIRC it's just replacing `apache2` with `nginx`.

Comment: Matt, I get everything all figured out. Thanks for the help.